# Disable Textbox based on CanExecute of command

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I have a button and a Textbox, I've setup the button to a command using MVVM, `INotifyPropertyChanged` and MVVM.

However I want the Textbox to be disabled when the `CanExecute` method of the command returns `false`, i.e. I want the Textbox to be disabled when the button is disabled.

How do I hook a `Textbox` only to a command's `CanExecute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TextBox` doesn't have a `Command` property that you can bind directly to an `ICommand` source property.

Depending on the relationship between the `TextBox` and the `Button` in the view, you may bind the former's `IsEnabled` property to the second's:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="..." Command="{Binding Command}" />
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=btn}" />
```

This only works if the controls belong to same [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes). If they don't, you should add a `bool` property to your view model and return the value of this one from the `CanExecute` method of the command, and also bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `TextBox` to it.